# Visual Studio 2013 and Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I tried to do quickstart for Angular 2.0 using Visual Studio 2013.
I installed TypedScript 1.5 and created a new project called "HTML Application with TypedScript".

app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />    
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
})

@View({
    template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>',
})

// Component controller
export class MyAppComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Alice';
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

On build I get error "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided" on line 2 (import...).

Please, help me. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to get Angular2 to work with visual studio 2013? If yes, how were you able to resolved?

Comment: Alexander Zhidkov answered the question correctly. You need to set your TypeScript module system to "System".

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project properties - TypeScript Build - set "Module system" to "System".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have a `tsconfig.json` file in your project to instruct the TypeScript compiler on how to compile your TypeScript to Javascript. Here is more info on [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json)